# Is there a way to check or display which users are currently logged on?

Tags: drupal

In Drupal, is there a way to check or display which users are currently logged on? I want users who are logged on to be able to see who else is on. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Who's Online block in Drupal Core. Enable that to show a list of online users.

Answer (score 0):

One of the default blocks Drupal implements is the *Who's online* one.
There are two settings you can change for that block: *User activity* (how long users are still considered online after they viewed a page), and *User list length* (the maximum number of currently online users to display).

In Drupal 8, and Drupal 9, the Views module is part of the Drupal core modules. The *Who's online* block is now a view, enabled by default. The following screenshot shows its settings.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: What happened to "Who's online" in Drupal 9? I can't find it.

Comment: In Drupal 8 and 9, the *Who's online* block is a view.